# Transform an non numbered list to a numbered list with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to transform

```
<Address>
    <Line>Some street1</Line>
    <Line>Some street2</Line>
    <Line>Some street3</Line>
    ...
</Address>
```

into

```
<Address1>Some street1</Address1>
<Address2>Some street2</Address2>
<Address3>Some street3</Address3>
<Address4></Address4>
<Address5></Address5>
```

The first xml is malleable and can be redefined if neccessary, however the second xml is part of a legacy system which cannot me changed.
Most of what I find, correctly, points me to using attributes but unfortunatly, its the element itself that I wish to edit.

Would anyone be able to assist or if not, point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As easy as this, and probably the shortest solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Line">
     <xsl:element name="Address{position()}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Address>
    <Line>Some street1</Line>
    <Line>Some street2</Line>
    <Line>Some street3</Line>
</Address>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Address1>Some street1</Address1>
<Address2>Some street2</Address2>
<Address3>Some street3</Address3>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of **[`xsl:element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement)** and AVTs (**[Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)**).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `<xsl:element>` element. In its `name` attribute, you can also supply an expression that is computed while running the XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="Line">
    <xsl:element name="{concat('Address', position())}"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**Update:** `position()` is one-based.

Comment: +1 - beat me by 4 seconds. Minor pick - position() is 1 based so don't think you need to add 1.

Comment: @nonnb: Oh, right, thanks. Updated my answer. Too used to zero-based-list languages ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by mangling a new element with the current `position()` :

```
<xsl:template match="/Address">
    <Addresses>
        <xsl:for-each select="Line">
            <xsl:variable name="elename" select="concat('Address', string(position()))"></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:element name="{$elename}">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each >
    </Addresses>
</xsl:template>
```